# Show modal dialog and pause code execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, showmodaldialog

We have a project that uses window.showmodaldialog which is now deprecated in Firefox and absent in Chrome.  This is used extensively throughout the project and relies on the fact that window.showmodaldialog pauses code execution.  We have been trying to find something that would work in it's place.  The jQuery dialog for instance works well but it doesn't pause code execution.  The functions in our project are structured like the following.  The code to refresh objects can't run until the modal dialog is closed.  There are many functions like this in our project so rewriting it with callbacks would be very time intensive.  Thanks.

```
function DoSomething(){
    window.showmodaldialog(url,...)

    //code to refresh objects, etc.
}
```

Comment: I'm reasonably sure using event handlers is your best bet here, even though as you say it'll be a time sink.

Comment: if you're not collecting a return, and this is janky, but you can throw from the end of a new showModalDialog() function you write, and eval the rest of the stack or arguments.callee.caller.toString().split(/showModalDialog[...]+/)[1] when the dialog closes. saves refactoring, but is it worth it?

Answer (score 0):

In case the call to the URL requires no interaction with the user, but is only there to update elements you should use a synchronous call via ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: theurl,
    async: false
});
```

A complete function that do this:

```
var modalCall = function(url){
     $.ajax({
         url: url, 
         async: false,
         crossdomain: true,
         error: function(){
             throw "BLOCK EXECUTION";
         }
     });
 };
```

A full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/894c6n1z/